# MYSQL use too much disk (read / write)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, hard-drive, write

I have big problem with my server. I am using Ubuntu linux version 22.04. The problem is in the write / read disk (light for the disk is all the time ON) when I have turn on apache (PHP) and MYSQL. Here is the picture (CPU process):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzv7h.jpg

My setting in **mysqlc.cnf**  are

```
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_slovenian_ci

user        = mysql
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer_size     = 44M
max_connections = 300
max_allowed_packet = 32M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
max_binlog_size   = 100M
```

Comment: Assume "HDD led is always lit", so what? What's the problem with it? Why are you concerned?

Comment: The I/O is dosen kilobytes per second which is **VERY** small!

Comment: Thenk you for the answer... But I don't understand whay if I have turn off the apache then the disk is quiet (nothing to write). When I turn apache ON the disk all the time write something, but I don't know what. Led indicator for the disk is ON alot. And when the LED is ON I have a problem to connect them (request time out). Computer is bussy...

Comment: **This** is what you had to write into the question. Not the "HDD LED is on" but "after Apache start the request is timed out". Well, when you [update the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1142908/edit) with that info,  attach relevant Apache error log entries too. And, what's its configuration, at least, non-default parts (that you changed)?

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: What command generated that jpg?